# Is it possible to store react router history in a query string param?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, pushstate

I want to put multiple react components on a single page that use react routers that don't use memory history so that the browser's back button works and so that URLs will be sharable. I've been looking for a library but haven't found one that would be able to store the router location in a customizable query string param and updated with the URL encoded route with `pushState`. Something like

```
<Router history={createQueryStringHistory({ key: 'myKey' })}>
    <Route path="/component" component={MyComponent}>
    <Route path="/component/:id" component={MyItem}>
```

then the url would be updated like

```
/?myKey=%2Fcomponent
/?myKey=%2Fcomponent%2F1
```

and if there were another React component on the page that used the same router, it could create the history with a different query string key. Would this be possible, and is there already a library out there that does this?

Comment: i think you can create double layer of routing. first for the actual endpoint. and next for the query. though i dont have any working samples. but that could be possible imo.

Comment: `<Route path=""` doesn't allow matching on query string params

Comment: no, you can create your own history. you take out the query part. inject into a new history instance, pass that instance to a router and do routing

Comment: Yea i'm thinking i'm going to have to create the `createQueryStringHistory` lib myself, just wondering if there is already something out there that does this.. :D

Comment: i think you have an edge case, which most of libraries wont implement. so you will be forced to create your own :D